# Logrotate for processes which never close log file descriptors

Tags: c, linux, logging, named-pipes, logrotate

I was wondering what are my options when it comes to doing logrotate
for processes which never close their file descriptors. I am aware of the
"restart the service" and *copytruncate* option. However, assuming that restarting the process is undesirable, the applications doesn't respond to SIGHUP, and *copytruncate* is non acceptable due to potential data loss, I'm not sure what options I have left.

One solution that came to mind is to have a named pipe already in place where
the process is about to log to. Have another utility read from that pipe (copying to another log file) and have it react to the SIGHUP signal (from logrotate).

**Now my question is, is there already a utiliy that I can use for this?
If not, why? Is there something inherently wrong with this approach?**

To test this out, I did 2 tests, one to confirm data loss with copy truncate,
and one more to test my 'named pipe + uitility' approach:

**Demonstrating copytruncate loss:**

*app.c*

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE* f = fopen("log.txt", "a");
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                fprintf(f, "Logging line %d\n", cnt);
            cnt++;
        }
        fflush(f);
    }
    fflush(f);
    fclose(f);
    printf("Wrote %d lines\n", cnt);
    return 0;
}
```

And an accompanying logrotate config:

```
$cat /etc/logrotate.d/logexp 
/home/synepis/git/logexp/log.txt {
    size 20M
    create 700 synepis users 
    rotate 4
    copytruncate
}
```

Finally, I ran the application, during it's run I kicked off logrotate manually a few times via:

```
logrotate --force /etc/logrotate.d/logexp
```

App results:

```
./app
Wrote 100000000 lines
```

Log line count:

```
$ cat log.txt* | wc -l
69091700
```

**Log utility approach:**

I implemented a simple utility 'loghup' which creates a named pipe 'log.txt' and then simply reads of it to 'safe_log.txt'.
Finally, it responds to SIGHUP by reopening the file (thus starting a new log rotation).

*loghup.c*

```
int sighup = 0;

void sig_handler(int signo) {
    if (signo == SIGHUP)
        sighup = 1;
}

void do_piping(char *input, char *output) {
    int fi = open(input, O_RDONLY);
    int fo = open(output, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);

    size_t ret;
    char buff[4096];
    while((ret = read(fi, buff, 4096)) != 0) {
        if(ret == -1 && errno == EINTR) { // Retry later
            continue;
        } else if (ret == -1)  {
            break; // Error occured
        }

        write(fo, buff, ret);

        if (sighup) { // Reopen output log file on SIGHUP
            close(fo);
            fo = open(output, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);
            sighup = 0;
        }
    }
    close(fo);
    close(fi);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *input_file = argv[1];
    char *output_file = argv[2];
    signal(SIGHUP, sig_handler); // Setup signal handler
    mkfifo(input_file, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);  // Create named pipe
    do_piping(input_file, output_file);
}
```

New logrotate config with SIGHUP:

```
$cat /etc/logrotate.d/logexp 
/home/synepis/git/logexp/safe_log.txt {
    size 20M
    create 700 synepis users 
    rotate 4
    postrotate
        /bin/kill -SIGHUP $(ps aux | grep "[l]oghup" | awk '{print $2}')
    endscript
}
```

Then I ran:

```
./app
./loghup log.txt safe_log.txt
```

And forced logrotate a few times, finally:

```
$ cat safe_log.txt* | wc -l
100000000
```